# How to test whether an exception occurs or not in a Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
# controller
def index
  p = params[:p]        
  raise ABCException if p
end

# test
test "expect index controller raise ABCException" do
  assert_raise ABCException do
    # how do I write this block?
  end
end
```

I would like to call the *index* controller with *:p => true* to raise an exception.
I understand the assert_raise function, but don't know how to call controller as same as an end-user requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
assert_raise ABCException do
  get :index, :p => true
end
```